# How to prevent Keras predict_generator from shuffling data?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network, deep-learning

I created a deep learning model, and I want to check the performance of the model by using `predict_generator`. I am using the following code which compares the images' labels with the predicted classes and then returns the prediction error.

```
validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
            validation_dir,
            target_size=(image_size, image_size),
            batch_size=val_batchsize,
            class_mode='categorical',
            shuffle=False)

    # Get the filenames from the generator
    fnames = validation_generator.filenames

    # Get the ground truth from generator
    ground_truth = validation_generator.classes

    # Get the label to class mapping from the generator
    label2index = validation_generator.class_indices

    # Getting the mapping from class index to class label
    idx2label = dict((v,k) for k,v in label2index.items())

    # Get the predictions from the model using the generator
    predictions = model.predict_generator(validation_generator, steps=validation_generator.samples/validation_generator.batch_size,verbose=1)
    predicted_classes = np.argmax(predictions,axis=1)

    errors = np.where(predicted_classes != ground_truth)[0]
    print("No of errors = {}/{}".format(len(errors),validation_generator.samples))

    # Show the errors
    for i in range(len(errors)):
        pred_class = np.argmax(predictions[errors[i]])
        pred_label = idx2label[pred_class]

        title = 'Original label:{}, Prediction :{}, confidence : {:.3f}'.format(
            fnames[errors[i]].split('/')[0],
            pred_label,
            predictions[errors[i]][pred_class])

        original = load_img('{}/{}'.format(validation_dir,fnames[errors[i]]))
        plt.figure(figsize=[7,7])
        plt.axis('off')
        plt.title(title)
        plt.imshow(original)
        plt.show()
```

`validation_generator.classes` is arranged but `predicted_classes` is not arranged.

I take the code from here https://www.learnopencv.com/keras-tutorial-fine-tuning-using-pre-trained-models/

How can I prevent `predict_generator` from shuffling data?

Comment: I don't get what you mean by X is arranged but Y is not arranged.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro  the order of the items in validation_generator.classes is same as the order of the data in dataset. But predict_generator  does not do the predication in the same order of the dataset.

Comment: Please add detail of this, the classes attribute in the generator gives you the class indices, are you saying that the class indices do not match the output of the generator? If so, add examples of this. Also you should make sure that there are no new or unseen classes in the validation data (this would change class indices).

Comment: My code is same as the code in the link..  The data in validation_generator.classes is [0,0,0,0,....1,1,1,1,........2,2,2..]  But predict_generator changes the order of the data and make the predication for the images as  [1,1,1,...2,2,2,...,0,0,0] or [2,2,2... 0,0,0....1,1,1...2,2.. ]

Comment: I think the tutorial is not doing it right, it shouldn't be using generator.classes, but instead each time the generator is called it returns the image data and the corresponding label.

Comment: I found the solution here https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3296#issuecomment-349998110